# How to display data from Textbox to a Gridview using Arraylist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, generic-list, generic-collections

I have created two TextBoxes to enter the FirstName and LastName of an employee in a web-based ASP.NET application using C# on Visual studio 2010. There is a Button. when I click on it, the values that I enter in the TextBoxes should be displayed in a Gridview without those values being stored in the database. I have already implemented it using DataTables as shown below. But now I want to implement it using ArrayList. How can I do that? Can you provide a sample code to execute the above mentioned functionality?

How can I tweak the code given below, to implement the functionality using ArrayList instead of DataTables?

**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("FIRST NAME");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("LAST NAME");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = TextBox1.Text;
    dr1[1] = TextBox2.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1); 
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use *typed* list `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList` it will save you from lot of type casting in your code. You can read more about advantages of using types list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Make a class of lets say Employee with data members FirstName, LastName etc and make of list of Employees and bind it with `GridView`.

```
public class Employee
{
    public FirstName {get; set;}
    public LastName {get; set;}
    public Address {get; set;}
}

List<Employee> employees = List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new Employee{FirstName: "john", LastName: "Thunder", Address: "addr"});
gridView1.DataSource = employees;
gridView1.DataBind();
```